# Oracle SOA BPM issue

Tags: oracle, soa, workspace, business-process-management

I created instance at user level.but I am not getting same instance in oracle SOA BPM 11g workspace. these same issue facing in all the BPM interfaces in (DEV Environment ). please give me the solution for this...

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean. What is "creating an instance at user level"?

Answer (score 0):

Create a User and assign the role to the user in the "Security Realm" under user tab of weblogic console.

After adding user, make sure you have the role available under the groups tab. Add the respected role to user and logout from workspace and retry to login and verify for the instance. The instance should be visible in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For instance, the lane participant for the User task is Approver as shown above. The user should be assigned to this role in order to retrieve the task. Please make sure that the user is assign to the Approver role and this role is exist in the Application roles under Security Realm. HTH.